# Not able to clear left values from custom multi select picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, multi-select

I've created a custom multi-select picklist, in which values are also dynamic. But the left side values are not getting cleared, but it is getting added in right list.

Here is the **Apex code** :

```
public class multiSelect{

 /* variables for multiselect picklist */
public List<string> leftselected{get;set;}
public List<string> rightselected{get;set;}
public Set<string> leftvalues = new Set<string>();
public Set<string> rightvalues = new Set<string>();
/* variables for multiselect picklist */

//constructor
public multiSelect(){
    leftselected = new List<String>();
    rightselected = new List<String>();
}

public List<SelectOption> getunSelectedValues(){

        List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();
        Set<string> leftvalues = new Set<string>();

        //options.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = customobj__c.Services__c.getDescribe(); // my custom obj
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple){
            leftvalues.add(p.getValue());
            option.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getValue()));
        }

        system.debug('----leftvalues : '+leftvalues);

        List<SelectOption> options2 = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<string> tempList = new List<String>();
        tempList.addAll(leftvalues);
        tempList.sort();
        for(string s : tempList)
            options2.add(new SelectOption(s,s));
        return options2;
    }

    public PageReference selectclick(){
        rightselected.clear();
        for(String s : leftselected){
            leftvalues.remove(s);
            rightvalues.add(s);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference unselectclick(){
        leftselected.clear();
        for(String s : rightselected){
            rightvalues.remove(s);
            leftvalues.add(s);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSelectedValues(){

        system.debug('@@@@rightvalues : '+rightvalues);

        List<SelectOption> options1 = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<string> tempList = new List<String>();
        tempList.addAll(rightvalues);
        tempList.sort();
        for(String s : tempList)
            options1.add(new SelectOption(s,s));
        return options1;
    }
}
```

**Visual Force code :**

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="multibox">
                <apex:panelGroup >                       
                    <apex:selectList id="sel1" value="{!leftselected}" multiselect="true" style="width:100px" size="5">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!unselectedvalues}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:panelGroup>

                <apex:panelGroup >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!selectclick}" value="Add" rerender="multibox"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!unselectclick}" value="Remove" rerender="multibox"/>
                </apex:panelGroup>

                <apex:panelGroup >
                    <apex:selectList id="sel2" value="{!rightselected}" multiselect="true" style="width:100px" size="5">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedValues}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:panelGroup>

            </apex:panelGrid>
```

Comment: You might consider just using metadaddy's [Multiselect Picklist Visualforce Component](https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist)

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I don't want to go for component, rather need to go with apex class and visual force page only.

Answer (score 2):

You issue is how you are populating the unSelectedValues. You are pulling the value from a describe without filtering the selected value out.

Also, you are using a local variable inlace of the class variable:

```
public List<SelectOption> getunSelectedValues(){
    ......
    Set<string> leftvalues = new Set<string>();
    .....
}
```

so your changes to `leftValues` class variable are not reflected in that method since it uses the local variable

Since I am not confident that all your code is present I am providing you with a set of properties and methods in which this all works rather than trying to modify your code and making assumptions.

**Note** When you load the page you can initialize the unSelected and selected values with the appropriate data from your describes

```
private Set<String> unSelectedNames = new Set<String>();
private Set<String> selectedNames = new Set<String>();
public List<String> selected {get; set; }
public List<String> unselected {get; set; }

public [className](){

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = customobj__c.Services__c.getDescribe(); // my custom obj
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple){
        unSelectedNames.add(p.getValue());

}


public List<SelectOption> selectedOptions { get
{
    List<String> sorted = new List<String>(selectedNames);
    sorted.sort();
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (String s : sorted) 
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
    }
    return options;
    }
}

public List<SelectOption> unSelectedOptions { get
{
    List<String> sorted = new List<String>(unSelectedNames);
    sorted.sort();
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (String s : sorted) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
    }

    return options; 
    }   
}   

public PageReference selectName(){
    if (selected != null){
        for (String s: selected) {
            selectedNames.add(s);
            unSelectedNames.remove(s);
        }
    }       
    return null;
}

public PageReference selectAllNames(){
    if (unSelectedNames != null){
        for (String s : unselectedNames){
            selectedNames.add(s);
        }
        unselectedNames = new Set <String>();
    }       
    return null;
}

public PageReference unSelectName(){
    if (unselected != null){        
        for (String s: unselected) {
            unSelectedNames.add(s);
            selectedNames.remove(s);
        }
    }       
    return null;
}

public PageReference unSelectAllNames(){
    if (selectedNames != null){     
        for (String s: selectedNames) {
            unSelectedNames.add(s);
        }
        selectedNames = new Set <String>();
    }       
    return null;
}
```

<strike>Do not lazy load the left and right selected options</strike>

```
    public List<SelectOption> leftSelected { 
        get{

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (String s : leftValues) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
        }

        return options; 
        }   
    }
```

Without seeing the getters for your select options it is hard to say more

Comment: Sorry I'll add the getters as well, as I forgot to did it earlier.